# karaf 3.0.0, third party bundle javax.servlet dependency issue - requires [2.6.0,3.0.0)

Tags: apache-karaf

I'm trying to install a third party bundle into apache-karaf 3.0.0.RC1, but hit the error message:

```
Unable to resolve 67.0: missing requirement [67.0] osgi.wiring.package; 
(&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
```

It looks like the bundle requires servlet [2.6.0,3.0.0) - is this going to be possible on karaf 3.0.0.RC1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Karaf uses Pax-Web 3.0.1 you should install the html, html-whiteboard or web feature, it will install the required servlet api plus jetty and http service.